# How to select image(s) from the phone Library and delete them in cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I understand that you can use the cordova.camera plugin to retrieve the native url which I assume links to the original picture on the phone (ex library in iOS).

My question, is this true and how can you use this to delete the original image from the library?

One bet woulde be cordova.file, but which module to use and how to handle the vendor specific layouts?

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: you cannot delete with the cordova.camera plugin...

Comment: Is there another plugin which allows for this?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md is your best bet, but files are complicated due to vendor-specific layouts...

Comment: Read it through, but not directly seeing which module can help?